# How do I set up my email?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I just signed up for the Google Apps for Work trial version but can't seem to get an email service.

Answer (score 2):

There is still some setup on your part if your domain name was purchased from, for example GoDaddy. You will need to set your MX DNS Records to point at gmail's server.

If you do not have a domain name, that is step one of using Google Apps for Business. If you are just trying to use a Gmail address, well that's what Gmail is for ;)

Answer (score 0):

During the sign up process you specify an email address & a password, this is the "email service" that you are provided access to directly through Google's Gmail client.

Simply go to the [Google Apps for Business Dashboard](https://www.google.com/intx/en_uk/work/apps/business/) and click the *sign in* link. You'll need to provide the domain name and make sure the drop-down box is set to the admin console / dashboard.

Once you're logged in, you can click onto the *Users* icon if you wish to add more users. To sign into your email service, simply visit the [Gmail website](https://mail.google.com/) and you're all set to send emails directly from the Gmail client using your personal domain name as the extension.